# Created a delete button with delete php function but does not work

Tags: php

I am creating a simple blog but I don't manage to make the delete button work.  I think I am missing out on the button? I am well aware of SQL INJECTION and PREPARED STATEMENTS.  I will be dealing with them later.
There are no errors with connection.
My delete query is in a function **deleteArticles()**  on this page:  **articles.sql.php**

```
    // DELETE
function deleteArticle($c){

    $item = $_GET['item'];

    $qryDeleteArt = 'DELETE FROM articles
                     WHERE artID = \''.$item.'\'';
    if (!mysqli_query($c,$qryDeleteArt))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($c));
  } echo 'success';


}

    // CONTROLER //
switch( $action ){

    case 'insert' : 
        $process = insertArticle($conn);    
        if( $process == 'ok' ) 
            header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
        else 
            $page = 'articleform';
        break;

    case 'update' : 
        $process = updateArticle($_GET[ 'item' ]);  
        if( $process == 'ok' ) 
            header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
        else 
            $page = 'articleform';
        break;

    case 'delete' : 
        $process = deleteArticle( $conn, $_GET[ 'item' ] ); 
        if( $process == 'ok' ) 
            header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
        break;
}

?>
```

Form is on this page: **home.php**

```
<div class="article">
      <h3>
       <?php 
       while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticles)){ 
       ?>
       <a href="index.php?page=articleform&article="><?php  echo $rows['artTitre'];  ?></a>

        <span><a class="btn" href="index.php?page=articles&action=delete&item=">supprimer</a></span>
        </h3>
        <p><em><?php  echo $rows['artDate'];  ?> - <?php  echo $rows['artAuteur'];  ?></em></hp>
        <p><?php  echo $rows['artContenu'];  ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find sending the item_id in your href's
Try adding this:

```
<a class="btn" href="index.php?page=articles&action=delete&item=<?=$rows['itemID']?>">  
<a class="btn" href="index.php?page=articleform&article=<?=$rows['artID']?>">
```

instead of your current links

Comment: @Ivil , I am having syntax error : Error: Erreur de syntaxe près de 'artID'];?>'' à la ligne 2

Comment: post the full code you are using, the message you gave cannot exist if you copied the code lvil supplied. He is not using the semicolon after the artId'] which dóes exist in your error message.

Comment: <span><a class="btn" href="index.php?page=articles&action=delete&item=<?=$rows['artID']?>">supprimer</a></span>

Comment: I think it has something to do with my query?

Comment: $qryDeleteArt = 'DELETE FROM articles WHERE artID = \''.$item.'\'';

Comment: @swissed print your query. do you get the item_id($item)?

Comment: @Ivil no i don't get the  item_id($item).

Comment: @Ivil Now the Delete button works with this code in my home.php  <span><a class="btn" href="index.php?page=articles&action=delete&item=<?php echo $rows['artID'];?>">supprimer</a></span>